# How to make random algorithm more efficient

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, random

I wrote a piece of code that simulate the binary numbers flow in the Matrix. It works perfectly fine, and whenever I run this code people ask if I am hacking something. Run on MacOS 10.12.3.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import random
import time

while True:
    for j in range(204): #my full screen terminal is 204 characters wide
        print(random.randint(0,1),end='')
        time.sleep(0.0001)
    print('')
```

However, this code is very inefficient and drains lots of battery. So is there anyway to make this code more power efficient? Also, I don't want to have a huge amount of I/O to my hard drive.

Comment: Generate a full line ahead, then print this full line. You would also be surprised how dependent this is on your terminal. (e.g. the terminal inside Eclipse IDE is probably 100 times faster than MS cmd).

Comment: @sascha I think this is actually what I did (I don't know about power efficiency), because when I try to print something, it won't get printed without finding a `new line character.` All the numbers are actually printed line by line. Maybe it has something to do with python's `stdout` buffer, but I am not sure.

Comment: I did not see that end='' + python3, but i'm pretty sure, building one big string and call print one time will be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you could improve it. One way would be to get the terminal width programatically:

```
import shutil

terminal_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
```

Another way would be to generate the random digits in one go. Here is a comparison of two different methods:

```
In [52]: %timeit ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 1)) for i in range(terminal_width)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 380 µs per loop

In [53]: N = 2**terminal_width - 1

In [54]: %timeit bin(random.randint(0, N))[2:].zfill(terminal_width)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 µs per loop
```

Combining the two, you get:

```
import time
import shutil
import random

terminal_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
N = 2**terminal_width - 1

while True:
    digits = bin(random.randint(0, N))[2:].zfill(terminal_width)

    print(digits)
    time.sleep(1/60)
```

Note that terminal scrolling may be a limiting factor in your script, so you may want to consider using the `curses` interface and draw it all in-place. Here's [an example project](https://github.com/devsnd/matrix-curses) of the original effect with the curses module.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I didn't know the existence of `curses` and `shutil` module. Maybe I should spend more time reading the 1897 pages documentation :)

Comment: To tell the truth though, this thing gave me a headache after my staring at the screen for 5 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Think about your frame rate, and, as @sascha said, generate your lines entire.

Also, you can probably just generate 500 random lines and repeat them, saving a bunch of calls to `random`.

So:

1. Create an array of 500 random strings, however-many characters wide.
2. Write your loop to just print the entire string.
3. Change your sleep time to something more realistic. Most video games target 60fps, and don't worry about falling to 30fps. For something like this, you could probably get away with something like 16-20fps. So, how fast is that in seconds?

   Your existing delay time of 0.0001 seconds, multiplied by 204 characters, gives us 0.0204 seconds per line. That's 50 lines per second, roughly. Slow down to 30 lines per second, and you probably won't notice much difference, but you'll be sleeping a lot longer.